# How do I use ColSums

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

```
G1G2Effect  WEIGHT2    Sim1    Sim2    Sim3    Sim4    Sim5    Sim6    Sim7    Sim8    Sim9   Sim10   Sim11   Sim12
1    -0.0312 2.833103 -0.0312 -0.0312  0.0000 -0.0312  0.0312  0.0000 -0.0312 -0.0312 -0.0312 -0.0312  0.0000 -0.0312
2    -0.0640 2.536790  0.0000 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640 -0.0640
3     0.0420 3.309074  0.0420  0.0000  0.0000  0.0420  0.0420  0.0420  0.0420  0.0420  0.0420  0.0420  0.0420  0.0000
4     0.0332 2.476224  0.0332  0.0332  0.0332  0.0332  0.0332  0.0000  0.0332  0.0332  0.0332  0.0332 -0.0332  0.0332
5     0.0000 2.265289  0.0302  0.0302  0.0302  0.0000  0.0302  0.0000  0.0302 -0.0302  0.0302  0.0000  0.0302  0.0000
6     0.0000 1.272609  0.0116  0.0000  0.0000  0.0116  0.0000 -0.0116  0.0032 -0.0102  0.0101
```

I have the data.frame above^. I am trying to make a new data.frame that is just the sum of each column.

```
df2 <- colSums(as.numeric(as.character(df1)))
```

but I am getting the error message

> Error in colSums(as.numeric(as.character(exam))) : 
>     'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In is.data.frame(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

What is going on?

Comment: If the columns are `factor`, use `lapply` to do this `lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: Are those factors?? - Strange

Comment: Did you try colSums (x, na.rm = FALSE)?

Answer (score 1):

The `as.numeric/as.character` works on `vector/matrix` and not on `data.frame`.   We need to loop through the dataset and convert it to `numeric` and then apply the `sum`

```
sapply(df1, function(x) sum(as.numeric(as.character(x)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

We can also do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate_all(funs(sum(as.numeric(as.character(.)), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

If we really need `colSums`, one option is to convert the `data.frame` into `matrix`, so the `factor` class gets converted to `character`, then change it to `numeric`, assign the `dim` to the dimension of original dataset and get the `colSums`

```
colSums(`dim<-`(as.numeric(as.matrix(df1)), dim(df1)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Sotos Yes, you are right.  I must have mistook it for mean.

Comment: Strange though that a data frame with only numerics got converted to factors. Never saw that before

Comment: @Sotos  if you look at the last row, in some cases, it is blank.  Probably that is the reason.  Perhaps the OP could have mentioned `read.csv("file.csv", na.strings= "")`

Comment: So I deleted my answer. But I don't see where you saw factor problems in the original question ?